# How can I see filenames for each commit in `hg log --follow FILENAME`?

Tags: mercurial

`hg log --follow FILENAME` returns a list of commits that represent the history of a file across copies/renames. How can I see the filename in each of those commits?

All of the template keywords pertaining to files seem to show files associated with the changeset, so I don't see an argument I can pass to `-T` to get this information.

Another (less ideal) approach I was considering was identifying which of those commits do renaming, and then walking the ancestors associating the latest known name with each commit. I think to do this I would probably need to use `-G` and parse the output, which seems tricky / error-prone (especially if it's not well-specified), so I'm hoping I can avoid that. I think git's "parent rewriting" feature might help here but I don't see that option in hg. Or really any machine-readable representation of the graph would work. Still, it would definitely be sad to have to be basically duplicating the work `--follow` is already doing for me.

Comment: I think this might work (if someone with more knowledge can confirm I'll turn it into an answer): (1) `hg debugindex FILENAME`. All revisions that appear in "linkrev" are associated with this filename. (2) Find all of them that have empty p1 and p2. For each of these, call `hg debugdata -m LINKREV`. (3) Find FILENAME in the manifest, identify the NODE, and then call `hg debugdata FILENAME NODE`. (4) Look for the `copy:` line to get the previous name. For each of these names, repeat from step (1). This should give us the data to associate every revision in the `git log` output with a filename.

Comment: It seems the `hg debugdata -m` step can be cut out if we pass `--debug` to `hg debugindex` so that the full nodeid is displayed.

Comment: Does this work for you: `hg log --follow some_file --template {rev}:{file_copies}\n`.  That should indicate in each changeset what file was copied from another.

Answer (score 1):

TortoiseHG can do this in its GUI which is useful in itself and might also point to a solution.

In THG Workbench, pick a commit which has the file you are interested in. In the list of files in that commit, select said file. Right click and use the 'File History / Annotate' option.

The window it brings up consists of a table including the revision #, description, and **the filename as of that revision**.

---

Under the hood THG is issuing this command:

```
hg --hidden annotate --line-number --text --rev=123456 --number -Tpickle --file path/to/file.ext
```

The `pickle` template format produces a lot more information than shown in the GUI so apparently THG is parsing that and just extracting what it needs. Perhaps doing that yourself would also be possible.